# Euler's Project #3 Output Error

Tags: java, syntax, primes

I am currently attempting problem 3 of Euler's Problems and I have run into the problem where when the below code is compiled, all I get is "1" as output even though the for loop makes it run over multiple times. I have lowered the number down to 30 to try to find the problem but I have not found it. Looking at other solutions, my solution's logic is exactly the same.

```
public class eulerproblem3
{

public static void main(String[]args)
{
   int current = 1;
    for (int test=1;test==30;test++)
          {
        if ((30%test)==0)
        {
            boolean a = testPrime(test);
            if ((a==true)&&(test==current))
            {  
                System.out.println(current);


            }
        }

    }


  }
  private static boolean testPrime(long test1)
    {
        for(long ref=2; test1==ref; ref++)
        {
            if ((test1%ref)==0)
            {   
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: When `test` is `1` then `test != 30` so your loop is skipped.

Comment: Both your For-Loops are incorrect. You are checking equality to a single number (`test==30`)(`test1==ref`). You should be using `test<=30` and `ref<=test1` respectively.

Comment: Have you considered looking at implementing the sieve of Eratosthenes? I think from your code here the sieve might be a faster solution. ps the other guys are right about the for loop.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: @MrPublic Shouldn't test==30 work as a termination command as well so after 29 cycles, test is now 30 and the for loop terminates? or is there something I am missing?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The second is the termination conditions right? So only when test is 30 it will end the loop?

Comment: @Roger Ho The second part of a for-loop must hold true for the loop to run. It does not mean that the loop will terminate once it evaluates to true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conditions of your `for`s will be always false. You probably want something like

```
for (int test = 1; test < 30; test++)
```

Comment: I've changed all my for loops, but there is still no output. Would it be because of the code takes too long to run? or is there another fault in my code?

Comment: Because this condition is never true `if ((30%test)==0)`. What is for?

Comment: `if ((30%test)==0)` is for checking if `test` is a factor of 30, if it is, shouldn't the condition be true?

Comment: You're right but testPrime already checks for factor. it has no point for me that if. and even this check `(test==current)`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't testPrime testing whether the factors yielded from the `if ((30%test)==0)` is a prime? You are right about the second part though.

Comment: Can you open another question with the updated code? I'm confused